# How do I cross a highway with a railroad?

Tags: simcity-4

I'm playing *SimCity 4 Deluxe* (on Steam) and am trying to build a bridge (or something to the same effect) for a railroad to cross a ground highway.  How can I achieve this?

Here a screenshot of my situation:

[image]

Comment: Without mods, i'm not sure you can.

Comment: Solved with "Network addon mod" http://community.simtropolis.com/files/file/26793-network-addon-mod-for-windows-installer/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to do that is through the underground crossover exploit. You will never be able to achieve that in the normal way.
Here is what I mean!![image]

As you can see if both the segments are underground there is an exploit/bug which allows such crossovers to exist.

Comment: Solved with this mod: http://community.simtropolis.com/files/file/26793-network-addon-mod-for-windows-installer/

Comment: Oh man! That's very ugly! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Highways can pass *OVER* roads, but roads my not naturally pass over highways. For the road to pass over the highway, the road will need to be built first.

Comment: Does the same hold true for railroads though?

Comment: I think so. It's been a long time since I last did this. With railroad in Simcity 4, you can always transition from surface to underground, so you can just go under a highway if you really want to cross it and then transition back to surface. It is expensive, but anything dealing with the highway is going to be expensive.

Answer (score -1):

You have to build the rail first then elevated highway over it. You also must leave lots of space to make the ground to elevated highway transition.